# iOS Safari debugging: How can I see the actual remote screen on desktop?

Tags: ios, safari, safari-web-inspector

While remotely debugging iOS Safari (via USB connection between the device and desktop)...

... is it possible to see the ***actual iOS device screen***, within the debugging context, in Safari (desktop)?

Similar to Chrome remote debugging dev tools, I can inspect code, observe the console and do all kinds of stuff. However with Chrome you actually see the remote screen next to the code inspector.

Comment: I also want this. I want to give desktop access to another developer who's debugging iphone issues (he doesn't have a Mac). With this feature, via screen sharing, he could have full control of both phone and debugging context, and I would not have to be physically present to run through iphone test cases.